# ollydbg: how to set a breakpoint at program exit?

Tags: ollydbg, debugging

How can I break right when the program I am debugging quits? I don't know how to even locate the relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a break on TerminateProcess and friends when it breaks see the call stack and backtrack from there